# OCI8 - oci_connect fails if not setting TNS_ADMIN environment variables explicit in script

Tags: php, oracle-call-interface, oci8

installed PHP5 and OCI8 on openSUSE 13.1 works fine so far. When trying to run *.php on my Apache to connect to oracle databases via tnsnames.ora file, I'm getting ORA-12154. When I add the line

```
putenv("TNS_ADMIN=/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client");
```

everything works. I looked into phpinfo() and got 3 machtes when searching for TNS_ADMIN:

```
APACHE ENVIRONMENT: TNS_ADMIN           /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client
PHP VARIABLES:      _SERVER["TNS_ADMIN"]    /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client
APACHE ENVIRONMENT: TNS_ADMIN           /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client
```

(Yeah I got Apache Environment  2 times, on my phpinfo(), dunno if this is correct.)

Can someone help me getting PHP to use this variable ... I don't wanna use the putenv command in every script ... when using php script.php locally on the machine I got no probs and I don't have to set this TNS_ADMIN ... weird, I think ...

Any ideas?

Comment: Check the user account which PHP is run on in production environment. Chances are that it doesn't have ORACLE_HOME or TNS_ADMIN environment variables set.

Comment: I recommend you switch to using the [Easy Connect](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e41945/naming.htm#NETAG255) method. It completely eliminates the headache of dealing with an TNSNAMES.ORA file.